# Using Greens function to solve Laplace's Equation in quarter plane with Dirichlet and Neumann conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, greens-function

I have been recently learning (or trying to learn) about Green's functions. For some reason, it is a concept which I am having great difficulty understanding. I have a question here and I was wondering if someone would be able to give me some tips on what to do?
Any help would be much appreciated

Consider a domain $D = \{(x,y) |x>0, y>0\}$,
Let **x**$=(x,y)$ and $\xi=(\xi_x,\xi_y)$.

Find the Greens Function, $G($**x**, $\xi)$, such that 
$\nabla^2G = \delta($**x**$-\xi),\space  x \in D$,

subject to $G(0,y,\xi) = 0$, for $y>0$

and $\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}(x,0,\xi) = 0$, for $x>0$

Use this to solve $\nabla^2u=0$, $x\in D$ subject to u tends to zero as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$

$u(0,y) = h(y)$ for $y>0$

and
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,0) = g(x)$ for $x>0$

I believe that I have found the appropriate Green's function but now I am unsure how to use this to find what $u$ is when there are both Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions

The Green's function that I found was:
$\frac{1}{4\pi}\ln\big|\frac{((x-\xi_x)^2+(y-\xi_y)^2)((x-\xi_x)^2+(y+\xi_y)^2)}{((x+\xi_x)^2+(y+\xi_y)^2)((x+\xi_x)^2+(y-\xi_y)^2)}\big|$

And then I used the following formula:
$u(\xi_x,\xi_y) = -\int_0^\infty Gg(x)|_{y=0}\space dx\space- \int_0^\infty h(y)\frac{\partial G}{\partial n}|_{n=0}\space dy$
And got my answer as:

$-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty g(\alpha)\ln\frac{(\alpha-x)^2+y^2}{(\alpha+x)^2+y^2}d\alpha + \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty h(\beta) \frac{(\beta - x)^2}{(\beta -x)^2+y^2}d\beta$

I would much appreciate it if someone would be able to tell me if I am correct or if I am on the right path

I've read many PDF lecture notes from the first page of google but I am still finding it difficult to understand what to do.

Comment: This should help you see where the framework comes from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_function#Green.27s_functions_for_the_Laplacian

Comment: Also, see the "engineering intent" behind the concept of *convolution*: https://books.google.com/books?id=XF8W9W-eyrgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=zorich+mathematical+analysis+II&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI3o25jJjSAhXKMyYKHS79CIcQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=convolution&f=false

Comment: Okay thank you, I have been trying quite hard and I have been making progress. I believe that I have no found the Green function. I am just now unsure how to use it to find u when there are both Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions